# Enabling/Disabling TinyMCE from View/Server side and Setting Content back into DIV

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

**My Question is,**

I have simplified my question more. How to use below code in server side or in view. Is there any workaround like @Html.IsAdmin than mceAddControl should call otherwise mceRemoveControl.

```
function toggleEditor(id) 
{
    if (!tinyMCE.get(id)) {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, id);
    }
    else {
        tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, id);
    }
}
```

**Second Question is**, In below case I have TextArea

```
<textarea id="contentDiv" rows="15" cols="100" style="width:100%">@Model.Page.Html</textarea>
```

I have saved HTML in DB from above TinyMCE TextArea like below in DB

tinyMCE.get('contentDiv').getContent()

**How I set DB HTML content back into TextArea**. I want this in View/Server side without using JavaScript

Like I saved

```
Testing
Testing

in DB saved
Testing<br />
Testing
```

but when I set the content back in TextArea I see Testing
Testing with HTML Tags.

I hope you understand my Question

Comment: could you please describe a little bit clearer what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Thariama , I try to add more info

Comment: TinyMCE is built in textarea, so in server you only need to build a viewmodel with a text fields like "public string Content{get;set;}". After that you should bind this field to your textarea. In server side, you set value to your field, it will be auto updating to your textarea. What's problem did you get?